# How much Algebraic Geometry should one know at the beginning of grad school?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, education

I'm a Canadian undergraduate planning to focus on Algebraic Geometry.  In Canada a Masters is typically completed before a PhD, though I'm also open to school elsewhere, and I know some places you jump right into PhD.
I recently grabbed a copy of Hartshorne and have started reading/working through problems, and have Vakil's note on my laptop.
Where is my knowledge of Algebraic Geometry expected to be at the beginning of a Masters? or PhD?  In Vakil's suggestions to potential PhD students, he suggests completing most of the exercises in Hartshorne before becoming his student.
I was planning on doing the first 3 chapters by the time I start my Masters/PhD in a about a year and a half.  Is that possible?  Reasonable?  Will this give me an edge, or is it the bare minimum for preparation?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, it depends on where you are doing your Masters and/or PhD...

Comment: What you should do is ask someone who knows at the place where you are going to be doing this.

Comment: I haven't even applied to any grad schools yet, let alone received any letters of acceptance, so I don't know where I'll be going.  
I'm sure it comes down to specific universities, but let's say I got in to a top 20 school.  Surely there are some rough guidelines.

Comment: «Surely there are some rough guidelines» are great last words.